# Asp.Net User Control does not work correctly when multiple are added to one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have made a user control that allows an image to be uploaded and then cropped, but when I have several of these controls on one form, only the last one added will work correctly. The issue is the function storeCoords, has no effect on the X,Y, W and H hidden fields, thus when the crop 'rubber band' is moved, these values do not change. With the final control added, as the 'rubber band' is moved, the hidden fields are updated, and everything then works as expected. Why when I have several of these controls on one page does only the last one's javascript work as expected.

```
<script src="/Controls/ImageUploadAndCrop/Javascript/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="/Controls/ImageUploadAndCrop/CSS/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function ()
    {

        var elem = $('#<%= CropImage.ClientID %>'),
            boxWidth = elem.width(),
            boxHeight = elem.height();

        elem.Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords,
            boxWidth: boxWidth,
            boxHeight: boxHeight
        });

        $('#<%=CropButton.ClientID%>').click
        (
            function ()
            {
                var cropImg = $('.jcrop-holder img');

                $('#<%= ImgWidth.ClientID %>').val(cropImg.width());
                $('#<%= ImgHeight.ClientID %>').val(cropImg.height());
            }
        );
    });

        function storeCoords(c)
        {
            $('#<%= X.ClientID %>').val(c.x);
            $('#<%= Y.ClientID %>').val(c.y);
            $('#<%= W.ClientID %>').val(c.w);
            $('#<%= H.ClientID %>').val(c.h);
        }
 </script>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="UploadPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" Text="Upload" />
        <asp:Label ID="ErrorLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="CropPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Image ID="CropImage" runat="server"/>
        <br />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="X" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Y" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="W" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="H" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="ImgWidth" runat="server"/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="ImgHeight" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="CropButton" runat="server" Text="Crop" OnClick="CropButton_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="CroppedPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Image ID="CroppedImage" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot reuse ID's over and over. If you have multiple elements on a page all with the same ID, then only the `last element in the DOM with that ID` will have any actions taken against it. You must use classes, and refer to the controller you're working in as `this`. As it stands, the code above will not achieve the intended result.

Comment: I am not sure but I think `S(window).on` executes only once when the window object is loaded and that is when your last usercontrol is added to the page, you should change this to accomodate every single user control seperately.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Can you please give a code snippet?

Comment: `<div id="george"> Stuff 1 </div> <div id="george"> Stuff 2 </div>`. In this example, only the 2nd div with an `id="george"` will have any code ran on it because it's the last element in the DOM with that ID. ID's are unique and non-reusable.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, ASP automatically renames all the client side IDs so I don't think the IDs are the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few problems with this control:

1.

```
 var elem = $('#<%= CropImage.ClientID %>'),
            boxWidth = elem.width(),
            boxHeight = elem.height();
```

Shouldn't these lines to be followed by a semi-colon ";" and not a comma? But maybe is a typo.

2.

Because you are using this control in several places of the page, you need to take care of the "duplicate" appearances of any JavaScript code:

For example the following `<script>` tag will appear every time you the control is added to the page.

```
<script src="/Controls/ImageUploadAndCrop/Javascript/jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

This however won't do anything bad to functionality (I think?!), but the following function will do for sure, because the JavaScript will have more copies of the same function with the same arguments. Which one is considered?

```
function storeCoords(c)
        {
            $('#<%= X.ClientID %>').val(c.x);
            $('#<%= Y.ClientID %>').val(c.y);
            $('#<%= W.ClientID %>').val(c.w);
            $('#<%= H.ClientID %>').val(c.h);
        }
```

A quick fix would be:

```
 elem.Jcrop({
            onSelect: storeCoords<%= CropImage.ClientID %>,
            boxWidth: boxWidth,
            boxHeight: boxHeight
        });
```

And

```
function storeCoords<%= CropImage.ClientID %>(c) { ... }
```

In this way you'll have unique function names.

However ASP .Net has mechanisms to handle user controls which use JavaScript. See [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stax6fw9)

Comment: With regards to point 1 I believe you can declare multiple things in a single statement by comma separating the values like this. With 2 then I totally agree. It is critical to analyse uniqueness of all names, not just HTML IDs, when doing usercontrols if there needs to be more than one on a page.

Comment: Point 2 is the solution. Thank you! As @Chris says, all names need to be analysed for uniqueness, and not just html ids.