# How to reference multiple identical user controls on a page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-interface

I'm trying to use several instances of an ascx control on a single page. Only the last control on the page works.  I understand from this post [[Asp.Net User Control does not work correctly when multiple are added to one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330722/asp-net-user-control-does-not-work-correctly-when-multiple-are-added-to-one-form]) that the problem is related to the IDs; somehow I'm trying to reuse the IDs and the specific control being edited is not referenced correctly. However, the code on that page is complex and I don't understand the answers.  I created a small example of my problem to demonstrate.

Here is my user control:

```html
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="testControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="Tempusforms.testControl" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getValue() {
            document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID %>").innerHTML = getIndex();
        }
        function getIndex() {
            return document.getElementById("<%=droppit.ClientID %>").selectedIndex;
        }
    </script>

    <span>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="droppit" runat="server"  OnChange="getValue();" >
                <asp:ListItem Value="Select a Value"></asp:ListItem>              
                <asp:ListItem Value="one"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="two"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="three"></asp:ListItem> 
            </asp:DropDownList>
        
    </span>&nbsp;Index Value = 
    <span>
        <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="mylabel" ></asp:label>        
    </span>
```

Here is the page that uses the controls:

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="userControlTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="Tempusforms.userControlTest" %>
<%@ Register src="../Common/testControl.ascx" tagname="testControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <uc1:testControl ID="testControl1" runat="server" />
            <br /><br />
        <uc1:testControl ID="testControl2" runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you show me how to make this work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET generates different IDs which include the UserControl ID so IDs aren't the issue here.

However the problem is with the JS code that you are including in the User Control. This gets repeated and bad things happen because of that obviously.

You should get those scripts outside the User Control and change them to use parameters.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(ctrlID) {
        document.getElementById(ctrlID).innerHTML = getIndex(ctrlID);
    }
    function getIndex(ctrlID) {
        return document.getElementById(ctrlID).selectedIndex;
    }
</script>
```

And you can call these functions from the User Control like this: `OnChange="getValue(this.id);"`

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's working the way you said it would.